# My Ubuntu 20.04 spits out "logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory"

Tags: log, symbolic-link, devices, redirect, sockets

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. I am trying to run a script that needs access to /dev/log when the following error occurred "logger: socket /dev/log: No such file or directory". Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a file named *log* in the results of `cd /dev/ && ls`?

Comment: No, there is not..